# How to email the of contents of a file from a Azure blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, blobstorage

I wanted to connect to azure blob, get the file, read the contents of the file and send the content of the file through through an email.

Here is a picture description below.

[image]

NOTE : in the picture i want the content to be sent via the "Body" in the email.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide the work you have already tried and are having trouble with.

Comment: When you focus on "Body" parameter of the "Send an email" action, you should see the content of the blob showing up on the right hand side in the pop up for you to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dabbled with Azure logic apps to solve the last problem i posted ( i.e. How to dynamically get the file content from azure blob storage without specifically giving it the file name ). The answer was, just to pass the "Get blob content using path" connector instead of using "Get blob content " connector.

As an example, i've attached a picture below. In the picture - i'm trying to solve a problem : How to get and Parse(in to JSON) a csv file content loaded from azure blob storage and send the parsed file content into to my email.

**NOTE:** the parsing from csv to JSON is a custom azure function

If anybody wants the parsing azure function code, i can post it underneath later.

Hope this could help for anyone looking to solve the same kind of problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you would get the blob content to send to email, you could add a "**Get blob Content**" action **before** "**Send an Email**" action.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage).

Comment: Excellent, that would solve my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Excellent, that would solve my problem. Thank you so much.

On another note, let's just say i don't want to specify the file type - as in for instance i'm getting different files at different times and i want my logic apps to get the file contents of each file automatically when they are uploaded or modified. How can i do that ? thanks for the help again.

Comment: According to your demand, it seems that there is no action satisfy your requirements. If you still want to do it with logic app, you could use Blob trigger in Azure function with `"container/{name}"` to get any type blob update trigger and get the content then. However, as I test, I could not get the blob content when put azure function as an action.

Comment: this answer isn't viable anymore. it won't let you send the file content in the body or the attachment body. just the attachment name. incredibly frustrating.

Edit: you need to edit the .json to be able to change this